# Get all keys from (search.h) hash search table

Tags: c, hashtable

I'm using the `search.h` library to define a hash table through the `hcreate` function.

How can I go through all the keys in that table? `hsearch` always expects an entry to search for (or store).

[This](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/hcreate.html) is the documentation to all the three functions that manage the hash table ( `hcreate`, `hsearch` and `hdestroy`) but there's not mention of how to iterate through the structure to obtain all the stored keys.

When storing an entry in the table, I `malloc` the key value and so would like to have an easy way to free those `malloc`'d values.

Can I avoid having to store those in a separate structure such as an array?

I wouldn't expect `hdestroy` to be doing this automatically for me, as it has no way of knowing if `key` points to dynamically allocated or static memory (or indeed if I haven't already freed that memory).

Switching to a different hash search table library is not an option. I have to work with this. I'm on CentOS and use GCC 4.1.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard functionality of iterating through the entries of the hash table. This question is addressed [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hash-Search-Function.html) (in the `hdestroy` section):

> It is important to remember that the elements contained in the hashing
>   table at the time hdestroy is called are not freed by this function.
>   It is the responsibility of the program code to free those strings (if
>   necessary at all). Freeing all the element memory is not possible
>   without extra, separately kept information since there is no function
>   to iterate through all available elements in the hashing table. If it
>   is really necessary to free a table and all elements the programmer
>   has to keep a list of all table elements and before calling hdestroy
>   s/he has to free all element’s data using this list. This is a very
>   unpleasant mechanism and it also shows that this kind of hashing
>   tables is mainly meant for tables which are created once and used
>   until the end of the program run.

Comment: Good link, I thought this was just some oddball 3rd party library. Note the safety warnings: `MT-Unsafe race:hsearch | AS-Unsafe heap | AC-Unsafe corrupt mem`, which just confirms my instinct to avoid it at all costs.

Comment: Thanks, looks like there's no getting around storing all malloc'd elements in a separate structure.

Answer (score 3):

Without looking at the actual source of the library, I would say there is no way walk the hash table after it has been created. You would be required to remember the pointers for your malloc'd memory in a separate structure.

Frankly, I don't think I'd touch that library with a ten foot pole. The API has numerous problems

- Atrocious documentation
- The library can only support a single hash table (note that `hcreate` does not return a handle which is then passed to `hsearch` or `hdestroy`)
- The inability to walk the table, or retrieve the keys severely limits its uses.

Instead, depending on your platform (you don't say whether you are on Windows or a Unix-based OS), I'd take a good long look at `glib` which supports a rich set of data-structures ([documentation home](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/))

The docs for hash tables are [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.42/glib-Hash-Tables.html). That's for v2.42 of the library - they don't have a generic link for the "latest version".

`glib` is the core of GNOME (the Ubuntu UI) but you don't need to use any of the `gmainloop` or event pump related features.

Comment: Not sure the version of`glibc` in your environment, If you take closer look at man page of `hcreate()` , there is actually re-entrant and thread-safe version of the function `hcreate_r()` which allow application to use several hash tables by specifying  `struct hsearch_data *` as a handle